How to Type cast to the base template class in c#
C# experts , Please look in to the below code and please let me know what is the best way to typecast to the parent template processor class . This doesn't work , does it require a explicit type cast using explicit?
processor = (FruitJuiceProcessor) grapesprocessor;
processor = (FruitJuiceProcessor)orangeprocessor;
Sample code below
 public static FruitJuiceProcessor<Fruit> GetProcessor(string name)
 {
     FruitJuiceProcessor<Fruit> processor = null;
     if (name == "Grapes")
     {
       FruitJuiceProcessor<Grapes> grapesprocessor = new GrapesFruitJuiceProcessor();

         processor = (FruitJuiceProcessor<Fruit>) grapesprocessor;
     }
     else if (name == "Orange")
             {

         FruitJuiceProcessor<Orange> orangeprocessor = new OrangeFruitJuiceProcessor();

         processor = (FruitJuiceProcessor<Fruit>)orangeprocessor;
     }
    return processor ;
 }

Full Code with the processor and the fruit classes
FruitJuiceProcessor<Fruit> processor = GetProcessor("Grapes");

public class Fruit
{
    public string Quality
    {
        get; set;
    }
    public string Name
    {
        get; set;
    }
    public string Origin
    {
        get; set;
    }
}

public class Grapes : Fruit
{

}

public class Orange : Fruit
{

}


public abstract class FruitJuiceProcessor<T> where T : Fruit
{

    public abstract List<T> ProcessFruit();

    public List<T> Process()
       {
         return ProcessFruit();
       }
}


public class GrapesFruitJuiceProcessor : FruitJuiceProcessor<Grapes>
{
    public override List<Grapes> ProcessFruit()
      {
        List <Grapes> ProcessedGrapes = new List<Grapes>();

        return ProcessedGrapes;
      }
}



public class OrangeFruitJuiceProcessor : FruitJuiceProcessor<Orange>
{
    public override List<Orange> ProcessFruit()
     {
        List<Orange> ProcessedOranges = new List<Orange>();

         return ProcessedOranges;
     }
}


Your FruitJuiceProcessor<T> doesn't use T anywhere within its method declarations, which I suspect is not representative of your real use case. How you use T will very significantly affect the answer here.

For this sample code , i haven't mentioned it. But in the main code it uses the T , for eg:  List availableFruits = ProcessFromRepository();

It's really important information though. Because without knowing whether T could be covariant or contravariant, it's impossible to suggest perhaps introducing an interface for example. You're asking us to give an answer when we've only got half the relevant information.

Sorry for that. I have updated the code. Thanks

Hello @JonSkeet Appreciate if you provide any inputs on this. Thanks

In C# you cannot do this kind of casts, but you can create an internal interface as base of FruitJuiceProcessor<T> with the abstract declarations of the methods shared between your specialized fruit processors:
internal interface IFruitJuiceProcessor
{
    void ProcessFruit();
    void Process();
}

public abstract class FruitJuiceProcessor<T> :
    IFruitJuiceProcessor where T : Fruit
{

    public abstract void ProcessFruit();

    public void Process()
    {
        ProcessFruit();
    }
}

and the GetProcessor method becomes:
public static IFruitJuiceProcessor GetProcessor(string name)
{
    IFruitJuiceProcessor processor = null;

    if (name == "Grapes")
    {
        FruitJuiceProcessor<Grapes> grapesprocessor = new GrapesFruitJuiceProcessor();

        processor = grapesprocessor;
    }
    else if (name == "Orange")
    {

        FruitJuiceProcessor<Orange> orangeprocessor = new OrangeFruitJuiceProcessor();

        processor = orangeprocessor;
    }

    return processor;
}

I used this pattern to create a database kind adapter and it worked very well. Remember also that is better to use nullable datatypes and handle the 'Not valid kind' case in this context.

Thanks @Frithurik for your inputs. when i tried with the T around interface , the casting fails

While I don't have a definitive answer, the problem is related to how abstract classes are resolved in C#. I don't believe there is a way to reference the abstract class in this fashion.
A solution would be to introduce an IFruitJuiceProcessor<T> into the mix and use that as your primary type to reference. Your code will still function properly:
IFruitJuiceProcessor<Fruit>? processor = GetProcessor("Grapes");

static IFruitJuiceProcessor<Fruit>? GetProcessor(string name)
{
    return name switch
    {
        "Grapes" => new GrapesFruitJuiceProcessor(),
        "Orange" => new OrangeFruitJuiceProcessor(),
        _ => null
    };
}

public class Fruit
{
    public string Quality
    {
        get; set;
    }
    public string Name
    {
        get; set;
    }
    public string Origin
    {
        get; set;
    }
}

public class Grapes : Fruit
{

}

public class Orange : Fruit
{

}

public interface IFruitJuiceProcessor<T> where T : Fruit
{
    void Process();
}

public abstract class FruitJuiceProcessor<T>: IFruitJuiceProcessor<T> where T : Fruit
{
    public abstract void ProcessFruit();

    public void Process()
    {
        ProcessFruit();
    }
}

public class GrapesFruitJuiceProcessor() : FruitJuiceProcessor<Grapes>, IFruitJuiceProcessor<Fruit>
{
    public override  void ProcessFruit()
    {

    }
}

public class OrangeFruitJuiceProcessor() : FruitJuiceProcessor<Orange>, IFruitJuiceProcessor<Fruit>
{
    public override  void ProcessFruit()
    {

    }
}

The big annoyance is having to implement both IFruitJuiceProcessor and FruitJuiceProcessor to get the same functionality.

doesn't IFruitJuiceProcessor need to be covariant, i.e. out T ?

Thanks @Tich .This did work for me , but as you said , i have to implement both. I have updated code in the original post so that the processfruit returns collection of  T. I would like to hear from others as well on this before implementing on the original code. Thanks
